# Function overloading from a base class when all types are not known

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, overloading

I've stumbled into a problem which, at a glance, is easy cplusplusable, but on careful study appears not to be.

I have items in my program which I will need to work with many types, so I have decided to handle these in a generic, extensible way:

```
class ItemBase
{
public:
 virtual ~ItemBase() = 0 {}
    // pure virtual class, some extra members
};

template<typename T>
class ItemT : public ItemBase
{
public:
 ItemT(const T &data) : m_Data(data) {}

 T m_Data;
};
```

I can now store any type in a collection:

```
std::vector<ItemBase*> items;
```

This is fine.  Now I have GUI components I want to keep separate from this class so I want to generate the GUI components depending on type:

```
GuiComponent* BuildComponent(ItemT<int> &item)
{
    // do whatever based on this type, the int is needed
}

GuiComponent* BuildComponent(ItemT<double> &item)
{
    // do whatever based on this type, the double is needed
}
```

Which is almost beautiful coding.  Unfortunately it does not work.  As this program shows:

```
std::vector<ItemBase*> m_Items;
m_Items.push_back(new ItemT<int>(3));
m_Items.push_back(new ItemT<double>(2.0));
BuildComponent(*m_Items[0]);
```

Because m_Items[0] is of type ItemBase*.

So how do I solve this problem?  What design pattern or template trickery can help me out here?

Comment: Are you getting compile time errors? Run time errors?

Comment: Compile time "none of the overloads could convert all argument types"

Comment: well, for one thing, your abstract declaration is incorrect. An abstract declaration should not have the {} after it. The {} is for the derived class to implement. That also means your ItemT class needs to implement the destructor for the base class.

Comment: It's called a pure virtual with a body : pretty uncommon, but perfectly legal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy answer would be : add a virtual `buildComponent` method in `ItemBase`. However, as you want to keep the GUI Components separated, I'd recommend a [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern.

A very simple implementation would consist of :

- Adding a single `accept(AbstractVisitorType &)` virtual method in `ItemBase`
- Implementing this method in every derived class by calling `visitor.visit(*this)`, which means that the `AbstractVisitorType` must provide a virtual `visit` method for every concrete type it might be called with (see note below)
- Provide a concrete implementation of this visitor which will instantiate the appropriate GUI object in each of its `visit` overload based on the parameter type.

Note however that the Visitor pattern is only appropriate for a reasonably stable class hierarchy : using a new instantiation of the ItemT template will require maintenance on the Visitor side to handle this new type (but your initial idea had the same issue).

Chapter 10 of Modern C++ Design (Andrei Alexandrescu) is a great read regarding the visitor pattern.

Comment: Yes, I understood I needed to maintain two class heirarchies in parallel.  Do you have a different idea I could use?

Comment: The visitor pattern is almost perfect.  Unfortunately I have to give this class knowledge of how it is going to be used, by including the header file with all these overidable functions in it.  It is a shame a virtual function cannot be templated.

Comment: struct Visitor
    {
        template<class T>
        void visit(const ItemT<T> &t) 
        { 
     T item = t.m_Data;
        };
    };

Comment: Glad it does :) You might want to google for acyclic visitor to go a little further (although it's a little overkill for your needs)